# Maximum number of files in Library?

Tags: content, contentworkspace

Does anyone know what the maximum number of files is in a Content Library? We are looking to add 300K and I can't find anything about limitations.

Additionally, if there isn't a limit, are there any known performance issues with too much content in a library? Along the lines of poorer performance with too many child records to a parent.

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure of the answer, i randomly decided to try 50K per library, and that works, so there's that.

Comment: Considering there have been no other answers this does provide a clear indication and could be seen as a partial answer imo. Stands out best now rather than part of the question or as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Salesforce Developer Limits Quick Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_features.htm):

> Content: maximum number of documents 10,000,000